# Как открыть layout при нажатии на FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код, при нажатии на  FloatingActionButton всплывает окно с тектом 
Replace with your own action, как вместо данного текста поставить какой нибудь layout?

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .setAction("Action", null).show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя, `Snackbar` не для этого придуман.

Нужно что-то сложнее текста показать, используйте диалоги:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html